# Issue with wrapping HTML label for check box

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where I cannot get a label (span) to stay inline with another `span`.

i've created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0z8xvv0n/ (excuse styles, they're copied from chrome for purposes of demonstrating the point.

What I'm trying to do is wrap the label but keep the label next to the `span` than represents the check box.  I've not included the :hover or checked styles, but wouldn't make a difference to the outcome

```
<div class="wcontrol">
    <div class=" wcheckbox-container form-group">
        <div class=" wcheckbox ">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label class=""><span class="wcheckbox-box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></span><span class="wcheckbox-label">This is a long check box label yeah, this is long and wont wrap properly?</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

It's pretty obvious that I'm using a custom HTML checkbox, and using a hidden checkbox input to hold the value.

Any ideas how I can easily solve this?

TIA

Comment: Do you want the "label" to wrap around and under the "checkbox" or do you want to preserve space under the "checkbox"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you:

Remove `float: left` and add `display: table-cell` to **.wcheckbox-label.** Also add `display: table-cell` to **.wcheckbox-box**

```css
.wcontrol {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    display: block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
.wcheckbox-container {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    display: block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: auto;
}
.wselect {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    display: block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: auto;
}
input {

    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    border-left-style: none;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    border-right-style: none;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    cursor: auto;
    display: block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 13px;
    left: -3000px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: start;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-rendering: auto;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 13px;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    writing-mode: lr-tb;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
label {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
.wcheckbox-box {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(205, 126, 115);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgb(205, 126, 115);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-right-color: rgb(205, 126, 115);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-top-color: rgb(205, 126, 115);
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table-cell; /*CHANGED*/
    float: left;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 22px;

}
.wcheckbox-label {
        border:1px solid red;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table-cell; /*CHANGED*/
    /*float: left; REMOVED */
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 22.4px;
    padding-left: 5.6px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wcontrol">
    <div class=" wcheckbox-container form-group">
        <div class=" wcheckbox ">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label class="">
                <span class="wcheckbox-box">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </span> 
                <span class="wcheckbox-label">
                    This is a long check box label yeah, this is long and wont wrap properly?
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE : DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0z8xvv0n/3/)

Comment: thanks!  not seen that before.  (sorry for terrible CSS dump too)

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float: left` and `display: block` on `.wcheckbox-label`.

That way the text flows naturally next to the checkbox.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0z8xvv0n/6/

Comment: nearly, but i want to keep the second line of the text indented. thanks for sharing though

Comment: I figured I might've misunderstood you once I saw divy3993's answer. Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a few adjustments to your CSS.  I added some comments in the following snippet that explain further.

```css
.wcontrol {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    display: block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
.wcheckbox-container {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    display: block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: auto;
}
.wselect {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    display: block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: auto;
}
input {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    border-left-style: none;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    border-right-style: none;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    cursor: auto;
    display: block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 13px;
    left: -3000px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: start;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-rendering: auto;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 13px;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    writing-mode: lr-tb;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
label {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
.wcheckbox-box {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(205, 126, 115);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgb(205, 126, 115);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-right-color: rgb(205, 126, 115);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-top-color: rgb(205, 126, 115);
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    cursor: pointer;
    /* display: block;
    float: left; */ /* don't need these */
    display: inline-block; /* this preserves the explicitly set dimensions whilst allowing .wcheckbox-label to wrap around it  */
    vertical-align: middle; /* align to the middle of .wcheckbox-label */
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 22px;
}
.wcheckbox-label {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(72, 72, 72);
    cursor: pointer;
    /* display: block;
    float: left; */ /* remove these to make the span default to inline */
    vertical-align: middle; /* align to the middle of .wcheckbox-box */
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 22.4px;
    padding-left: 5.6px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wcontrol">
    <div class=" wcheckbox-container form-group">
        <div class=" wcheckbox ">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label class=""><span class="wcheckbox-box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></span><span class="wcheckbox-label">This is a long check box label yeah, this is long and wont wrap properly? This is a long check box label yeah, this is long and wont wrap properly? This is a long check box label yeah, this is long and wont wrap properly? This is a long check box label yeah, this is long and wont wrap properly?</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```